# Android spinner: выбор вариантов и загрузка в БД

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-sqlite, contentprovider

Здравствуйте. Совсем зеленый в этой теме, начал только недавно. Большая часть приложения создана на основе курса сайта Udacity - Android Basics: Data Storage. Поэтому большая часть названий вида pet, gender, etc (оригиналы оставлены с целью разбора что и куда работает с оригинальными комментариями).

Приложение позволяет добавлять\редактировать акты, и отображать их в списке. Данные загружаются и извлекаются из БД SQLite с помощью контракта, контент_провайдера, и т.п..

Сейчас задача создать спиннер вида: "Вариант1", "Вариант2", "Свой вариант". При выборе пункта "Свой вариант" пользователь вводит своё значение в текстовое поле, которое потом загружается в БД, и подгружается обратно при входе в "Режим редактирования" акта.
Как создать спиннер с готовым набором данных знаю, а как создать "гибридный вариант" пока не могу понять.
Прошу прощения, если вопрос слишком нубский.

Код активности, где создается акт. В коде есть обычный спиннер, над вторым думаю:

```
public class CreateActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

    private static final int EXISTING_PET_LOADER = 0;

    private Uri mCurrentPetUri;

    private EditText mNameEditText;

    private EditText mBreedEditText;

    private EditText mWeightEditText;

    private Spinner mGenderSpinner;

    private Spinner mMNspinner;


    private EditText mMN2EditText;

    private int mGender = PetEntry.GENDER_UNKNOWN;

    private int mMN_M = PetEntry.M_1;

    private boolean mPetHasChanged = false;

    private View.OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            mPetHasChanged = true;
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mCurrentPetUri = intent.getData();

        if (mCurrentPetUri == null) {

            setTitle(getString(R.string.editor_activity_title_new_pet));

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else {

            setTitle(getString(R.string.editor_activity_title_edit_pet));

            getLoaderManager().initLoader(EXISTING_PET_LOADER, null, this);
        }

        mNameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_pet_name);
        mBreedEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_pet_breed);
        mWeightEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_pet_weight);
        mGenderSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_gender);

        mMNspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);


        mMN2EditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMN);


        mNameEditText.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        mBreedEditText.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        mWeightEditText.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        mGenderSpinner.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);

        mMNspinner.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);


        setupSpinner();
        //setupSpinner2();

    }

    private void setupSpinner() {

        ArrayAdapter genderSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.array_gender_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
      genderSpinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

        mGenderSpinner.setAdapter(genderSpinnerAdapter);

        mGenderSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                    if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.gender_male))) {
                        mGender = PetEntry.GENDER_MALE;
                    } else if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.gender_female))) {
                        mGender = PetEntry.GENDER_FEMALE;
                    } else if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.gender_femalele))) {
                        mGender = PetEntry.GENDER_FEMALELE;
                    }
                    else {
                        mGender = PetEntry.GENDER_UNKNOWN;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                mGender = PetEntry.GENDER_UNKNOWN;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupSpinner2() {

        ArrayAdapter genderSpinnerAdapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.array_test, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    genderSpinnerAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

        mMNspinner.setAdapter(genderSpinnerAdapter2);

        mMNspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
                    if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.good))) {
                        mMN_M = PetEntry.M_1;
                    } else if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.tak_sebe))) {
                        mMN_M = PetEntry.M_2;
                    } else if (selection.equals(getString(R.string.hrenovo))) {
                        mMN_M = PetEntry.M_3;
                    }
                    else {
                     // Поле со "Своим вариантом", пока просто длявида т.к. тип данных int
                        mMN_M = PetEntry.M_4;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                mMN_M = PetEntry.M_4;
            }
        });
    }


    private void savePet() {

        String nameString = mNameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String breedString = mBreedEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String weightString = mWeightEditText.getText().toString().trim();


        if (mCurrentPetUri == null &&
                TextUtils.isEmpty(nameString) && TextUtils.isEmpty(breedString) &&
                TextUtils.isEmpty(weightString) && mGender == PetEntry.GENDER_UNKNOWN && mMN_M == PetEntry.M_1) {

            return;
        }


        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, nameString);
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED, breedString);
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER, mGender);

        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_MN, mMN_M);


        int weight = 0;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(weightString)) {
            weight = Integer.parseInt(weightString);
        }
        values.put(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT, weight);



        if (mCurrentPetUri == null) {

            Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(PetEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);


            if (newUri == null) {

                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.editor_insert_pet_failed),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                // Otherwise, the insertion was successful and we can display a toast.
                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.editor_insert_pet_successful),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {

            int rowsAffected = getContentResolver().update(mCurrentPetUri, values, null, null);


            if (rowsAffected == 0) {

                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.editor_update_pet_failed),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.editor_update_pet_successful),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_create, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        if (mCurrentPetUri == null) {
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_delete);
            menuItem.setVisible(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_save:

                savePet();

                finish();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_delete:

                showDeleteConfirmationDialog();
                return true;

            case android.R.id.home:

                if (!mPetHasChanged) {
                    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(CreateActivity.this);
                    return true;
                }

                DialogInterface.OnClickListener discardButtonClickListener =
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(CreateActivity.this);
                            }
                        };


                showUnsavedChangesDialog(discardButtonClickListener);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (!mPetHasChanged) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }


        DialogInterface.OnClickListener discardButtonClickListener =
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        finish();
                    }
                };

        showUnsavedChangesDialog(discardButtonClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        String[] projection = {
                PetEntry._ID,
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME,
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED,
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER,
                PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT,

                PetEntry.COLUMN_MN };

        return new CursorLoader(this,   // Parent activity context
                mCurrentPetUri,         // Query the content URI for the current pet
                projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
                null,                   // No selection clause
                null,                   // No selection arguments
                null);                  // Default sort order
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {

        if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() < 1) {
            return;
        }


        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME);
            int breedColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED);
            int genderColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER);

            int spinnerColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_MN);

            int weightColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT);

            String name = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
            String breed = cursor.getString(breedColumnIndex);
            int gender = cursor.getInt(genderColumnIndex);

            int spinner = cursor.getInt(spinnerColumnIndex);

            int weight = cursor.getInt(weightColumnIndex);


            mNameEditText.setText(name);
            mBreedEditText.setText(breed);
            mWeightEditText.setText(Integer.toString(weight));


            switch (gender) {
                case PetEntry.GENDER_MALE:
                    mGenderSpinner.setSelection(1);
                    break;
                case PetEntry.GENDER_FEMALE:
                    mGenderSpinner.setSelection(2);
                    break;
                case PetEntry.GENDER_FEMALELE:
                    mGenderSpinner.setSelection(3);
                    break;
                default:
                    mGenderSpinner.setSelection(0);
                    break;
            }

            switch (spinner) {
                case PetEntry.M_1:
                    mMNspinner.setSelection(0);
                    break;
                case PetEntry.M_2:
                    mMNspinner.setSelection(1);
                    break;
                case PetEntry.M_3:
                    mMNspinner.setSelection(2);
                    break;
                default:
                    mMNspinner.setSelection(3);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

        mNameEditText.setText("");
        mBreedEditText.setText("");
        mWeightEditText.setText("");
        mGenderSpinner.setSelection(0); 

        mMNspinner.setSelection(0);
    }


    private void showUnsavedChangesDialog(
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener discardButtonClickListener) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.unsaved_changes_dialog_msg);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.discard, discardButtonClickListener);
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.keep_editing, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                if (dialog != null) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });


        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    private void showDeleteConfirmationDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.delete_dialog_msg);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                deletePet();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                if (dialog != null) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });


        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }


    private void deletePet() {

        if (mCurrentPetUri != null) {

            int rowsDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(mCurrentPetUri, null, null);


            if (rowsDeleted == 0) {

                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.editor_delete_pet_failed),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.editor_delete_pet_successful),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        // Close the activity
        finish();
    }
}
```

Примерно как пытаюсь сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы не задаете вопрос, вы просите помочь решить объемную задачу, решение которой потребует большого количества кода и и многих абзацев текста. Попробуйте разбить вашу задачу на маленькие подзадачи и решить каждую из них в отдельности. Тогда, может, и вопросы отпадут. А так вряд ли вам кто-то станет помогать

Comment: @P.Ilyin Прощу прощения, что так получилось.
С позиции новичка мне казалось, что решение кроется в правильной настройке спиннера и добавления пары строк в дальнейшем коде. Теперь же понимаю, что всё не так просто.
На ум пока пришел, как мне кажется,колхозный вариант - создание отдельной колонки для "своих вариантов" и условий в коде. Но пока, к сожалению, знаний для реализации не хватает.